# detailed guide for pgadmin deployment - Windows 7

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am an absolute new to postgresql, pgadmin and all it's tools. And with no python knowledge. I need to deploy pgadmin in as a web application on windows 7 os.
I have been trying the pgadmin's documentation from [the official site](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/server_deployment.html) , with no results. always errors, they ask u to do 1 2 3 but without where and how to check and so on....
I need a detailed guide for pgadmin 4 v 2 installation and deployment as a web application - with or without postgreSql.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

For *pgAdmin 4 v2.0* on *Ubuntu*, according to the [download page](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python-wheel/):

#### Install dependencies, create a virtual environment, download, install & configure

```sh
sudo apt-get install virtualenv python-pip libpq-dev python-dev

cd
virtualenv pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate

pip install https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.0/pip/pgadmin4-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

#### Configure

Override default paths and set it to single-user mode in the local configuration file:

```
nano lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
```

Write:

```
import os
DATA_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(u'~/.pgadmin/'))
LOG_FILE = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.log')
SQLITE_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.db')
SESSION_DB_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'sessions')
STORAGE_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'storage')
SERVER_MODE = False
```

#### Run

```
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

#### Access

Access at http://localhost:5050

#### Exit

Exit with Ctrl-C

#### Run again

```
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

#### Make a shortcut

```
touch ~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
chmod +x ~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
nano ~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
```

Write:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Now you can just run it with a simpler command:

```
~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
```

Ref: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Sorry, I forgotten to mention that I am working on windows 7

Comment: I have edited the question and it's title to fit the needs. Thank you @n33ma

Comment: It will be easy on linux, you can use Virtualbox to host virtual machine and install pgAdmin4 in it OR you can use docker image.

Comment: thank u for your comment, but I still need to deploy on windows 7 without a vm.

Comment: Steps are similar for windows too, you have to install python and Visual Studio C compiler manually ( required for PIP install command to compile pycrypto library) Just skip apt-get line and start from creating python virtual environment for windows